# Can we tell if a system is linear and time-invariant from its frequency response?

Tags: filters, linear-systems, laplace-transform

Given a system with a known frequency response in the S-domain. Is there a way to find whether the system is linear and time invariant?

My current understanding is that we need to take the inverse Laplace transform of the system and prove linearity in the time domain.

Edit:
As per the comments, given that the existence of Laplace transform imply linearity,
Is there an intuition on why the mere existence of the Laplace transform of a system would imply linearity?

Comment: If it has a frequency response (or Laplace transform, if you have an $s$-domain function), doesn't that imply that the system is linear and time-invariant?

Comment: The frequency response (Laplace transform) is the Laplace transform of the impulse response of the system.  Non-linear or time-varying systems do not have (single parameter) impulse responses. That an impulse response exists is enough.

Comment: *Is there an intuition on why the mere existence of the Laplace transform of a system would imply linearity?*  Please *edit your question* to include that query.

Comment: What about a system such as $y(t) = 3x(t) + 5$? Its impluse response is $h(t) = 3\delta(t) + 5$, but it is non-linear.

Comment: @MBaz Good point!  Perhaps "affine" is better? :-)

Comment: @Crataegus In my opinion, the answer to your question is No, it is not possible (in general) to look at a Laplace transform and determine whether it corresponds to the frequency response of an LTI system. On the other hand, if you are told that the Laplace transform actually is the frequency response of a certain system, then you can assume that the system is LTI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given a system with a known frequency response in the S-domain. Is there a way to find whether the system is linear and time invariant?

If by "known frequency response in the s-domain" you mean a Laplace transfer function* as a ratio of polynomials in s -- yes.  Laplace transform analysis on a system is not valid unless the system is linear and time invariant.  So, given a *valid* Laplace transform, the system is presumed to be linear and time invariant.

If you mean a *measured* frequency response -- no, that's a different animal.  You can measure the frequency response of any system, no matter how time-varying or nonlinear.  Whether such measurements are meaningful, or can be used to determine the degree to which** the system is linear and time-invariant, depends on the system and the care with which one does the measurements.

* Edited from the original "Laplace Transform" based on comments.

** No physical system is *entirely* linear and time-invariant; a few can be treated as such for all earthly purposes, and many can be very profitably approximated as such, or linear analysis would be a mathematical sideline, not a mainstream pursuit.

Comment: "given a valid Laplace transform" Isn't this a circular argument? You need to know that the system is LTI for the transform to be "vallid" (I would say "useful" instead).

Comment: Kinda, kinda not.  You either trust the person that handed you the transform to have known the system was valid, or you start with a transform and presume validity (and, hence, LTI).  Or, you just dig up the physical article and verify for yourself.

Comment: I would put it this way: you can't know, from the equation alone, whether there is a corresponding LTI system. With more context, it becomes possible.

Comment: If you have a transfer function as a ratio of polynomials you can always find a set of LTI differential equations that realizes that transfer function.  (More properly -- you can find an infinite number of them).  Were you thinking of more esoteric "transfer functions", like $H(s) = \mathrm{sinc} j s$ (which may or may not be realizable by a physical system; I don't know, but I did choose $\mathrm{sinc}$ on purpose).

Comment: Yeah, I meant in general. Obviously it's possible for some specific transfer functions.